# Questions to be answered immediately?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, fastest-gun

Is it a feature of Stack Overflow that questions must be answered the moment it was posted?

I have tried answering some questions, of course took some time editing my answer to look perfect. But, by the time I am posting the answer, the question is no more on the main page and it was never looked at by anyone. I am sure it would get some upvotes if it was posted a little earlier (maybe before some other answer got upvotes).

Comment: I wouldn't call it a feature, but it is [the reality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Comment: you better look at "active" page; it's where many SO regulars (ie those who read and vote posts) spend their time. The very fact of posting your answer [meta-tag:bump]s the question on top of "active page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not a feature; but many people do try and answer a question quickly as the first answer naturally has more time to be viewed by others visiting the same new question.

This is often referred to as the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Do note that when you post an answer, the question get's 'bumped', moved to the top of the 'Active' tab. And if your answer is good, it can still gather votes over the long term. Be patient!

Comment: So... it's not a feature, it's a bug?

Comment: @Yannis: Some people do want to squash me from time to time for beating them to an answer.. Does that count?